# HTML5 getCurrentPosition with Meteor

Tags: html, geolocation, meteor

I'm trying to use the html5 geolocation api with Meteor.
I'm using: 
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query);` in my js but it doesn't seem to work - I think it may be related to the timer ( http://docs.meteor.com/#timers ) restrictions Meteor has. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why these would conflict. I tested geolocation in my meteor app just now to be sure and everything worked fine. What are you doing with the handler? It could be that the handler is trying to access data that hasn't finished loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @lashleigh it was a loading problem

Here is the code that worked for me (I'm using Modernizr.js to detect geo-location)

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Session.set('loc','?');
  //alert(Modernizr.geolocation);

  function foundLocation(location) {
    console.log(location);
    Session.set('loc','lat: '+location.coords.latitude+', lan: '+ location.coords.longitude);
  }
  function noLocation() {
    alert('no location');
  }
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    var output;
    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);
      outpout = Session.get('loc');
    }
    return Session.get('loc');
  };
}
```

Comment: Sweet! I'm glad you were able to sort it out.